# How to set the content and scrolling insets on WKWebView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit, wkwebview, appkit

The `WKWebView` class doesn't support the `scrollView` property on macOS. Moreover it's view hierarchy doesn't contain an `NSScrollView` instance (I've checked using *view debugging* on 10.12)

Now is there another way to set the scrolling insets and content insets of a `WKWebView` on macOS? I'd like to place a translucent view overlaying its margins.

Comment: This has not been answered for too long. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the top inset, call the SPI [`-[WKWebView _setTopContentInset:]`, which takes a `CGFloat`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/950143da027e80924b4bb86defa8a3f21fd3fb1e/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKViewPrivate.h#L70). Other than this I'm not seeing anything else that can programmatically alter the insets :/